# Reinstall free app

Tags: ipad

How do you reinstall a free app that you deleted on an iPad? I tried to go into the App Store and go to updates and purchased and went to not on this device - because it was not a purchase it just says open! I can't reinstall it!

Answer (score 1):

I install via iTunes.

In this case when the device is connected go to the devices icon in iTunes choose  Settings -> Apps

You get a list of all apps that you have purchased.

Find the correct one and then hit the button to its right saying install.

this has now disapearred in later iTunes. Current is 12.7.5.9 and it was removed some time earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. Have you tried turning off and on your iPad?

Also you may try to close the App Store app and then opening it again. To do so, press the home button twice, swipe up the App Store, press home button again.

Open App Store again see if you can install the app.